# Create a C and C++ preprocessor using ANTLR

Tags: antlr4, preprocessor

I want to create a tool that can analyze C and C++ code and detect unwanted behaviors, based on a config file. I thought about using ANTLR for this task, as I already created a simple compiler with it from scratch a few years ago (variables, condition, loops, and functions).

I grabbed C.g4 and CPP14.g4 from ANTLR grammars repository. However, I came to notice that they don't support the pre-processing parsing, as that's a different step in the compilation.

I tried to find a grammar that does the pre-processing part (updated to ANTLR4) with no luck. Moreover, I also understood that if I'll go with two-steps parsing I won't be able to retain the original locations of each character, as I'd already modified the input stream.

I wonder if there's a good ANTLR grammar or program (preferably Python, but can deal with other languages as well) that can help me to pre-process the C code. I also thought about using `gcc -E`, but then I won't be able to inspect the macro definitions (for example, I want to warn if a user used a `#pragma GCC` (some students at my university, for which I write this program to, used this to bypass some of the course coding style restrictions). Moreover, `gcc -E` will include library header contents, which I don't want to process.

My question is, therefore, if you can recommend me a grammar/program that I can use to pre-process C and C++ code. Alternatively, if you can guide me on how to create a grammar myself that'd be perfect. I was able to write the basic `#define`, `#pragma` etc. processings, but I'm unable to deal with conditions and with macro functions, as I'm unsure how to deal with them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This question is almost off-topic as it asks for an external resource. However, it also bears a part that deserves some attention.

The term "preprocessor" already indicates what the handling of macros etc. is about. The parser never sees the disabled parts of the input, which also means it can be anything, which might not be part of the actual language to parse. Hence a good approach for parsing C-like languages is to send the input through a preprocessor (which can be a specialized input stream) to strip out all preprocessing constructs, to resolve macros and remove disabled text. The parse position is not a problem, because you can push the current token position before you open a new input stream and restore that when you are done with it. Store reported errors together with your input stream stack. This way you keep the correct token positions. I have used exactly this approach in my [Windows resource file parser](https://soft-gems.net/windows-resource-file-parser-and-converter/).

Comment: This is a good approach. Parr wrote something about this in his Antlr4 book, I think. I implemented a while ago a C++ parser with the Antlr CPP14 grammar but it only deals with #includes, not the harder macros, conditionals, etc. https://github.com/kaby76/Piggy/tree/master/Serializers/C.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I did my research before posting here and saw your project. It's a great help, but unfortunately, as it based on ANTLr 2 it looks quite hard to do the conversion. I'm working on my implementation, will share my progress if you interested :) BTW Great work in all antlr-related things, like the VS Code addon!!